# Angular - get all selected dropdown values with assigned custom css class with ElementRef

Tags: angular

I have two dropdowns:
`private elementRef: ElementRef`

```
<select 
  class="form-control same-group" 
  [(ngModel)]="selected" 
  (ngModelChange)="select($event)" 
  formControlName="age">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let x of collection" 
    [value]="x">
    {{x}}
  </option>
</select>

<select 
  class="form-control same-group" 
  [(ngModel)]="selected2" 
  (ngModelChange)="select2($event)" 
  formControlName="age2">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let x of collection2" 
    [value]="x">
    {{x}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I would like to select all values into array for dropdowns with same-group class appended as seen above.

So if value selected in first dropdown is "test" and in second "test", I would like to have ["test", "test2"].

How can I access this with ElementRef?

Comment: Didn't quite understand what it is that you're trying to do. A stackblitz or a pictorial representation would help understand better.

Comment: I want to access and store to array all selected values from all drop downs. Drop downs will be marked with specific css class to help access selected values.

Comment: so you want a single selection in one dropdown to give you values of the other if found is that so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Directive` and query(`ViewChildren`) the directive.
Then `read` the elementRef of the directive. With that acquired, you can then aggregate the selected values in array.

Comment: Any example possible?

Comment: Actually there is no need for that I mentioned above.
Does this suits you need?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-multi-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Updated the Stackblitz with directive approach